# Patterns for Compensating Lack of Inheritance in SOA

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soa

I find Inheritance and concept of base class as the strongest point of OOP.  But this is not encouraged in SOA. So,  what are the popular patterns for overcoming this limitation in SOA? Could you please provide tutorials that explains (with code demonstration in WCF) these patterns?

Note: This is NOT a general question about patterns available in SOA. But it is more specific to the above mentioned problem.

Note: I am using WCF for SOA.

---

Reading:

1. [“Do not use Abstract Base class in Design; but in Modeling/Analysis”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470013/do-not-use-abstract-base-class-in-design-but-in-modeling-analysis)
2. [How is an SOA architecture really supposed to be implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665024/how-is-an-soa-architecture-really-supposed-to-be-implemented)
3. [How to deal with Java Polymorphism in Service Oriented Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527481/how-to-deal-with-java-polymorphism-in-service-oriented-architecture)
4. [How to get up to speed on SOA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125831/how-to-get-up-to-speed-on-soa)
5. [What is service-oriented architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836900/what-is-service-oriented-architecture)
6. [Do DDD and SOA really play well together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351170/do-ddd-and-soa-really-play-well-together)
7. [SOA and WCF design questions: Is this an unusual system design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277662/soa-and-wcf-design-questions-is-this-an-unusual-system-design)
8. [Designing WCF data contracts and operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401809/designing-wcf-data-contracts-and-operations)
9. Expando Objects in C# 4.0

Comment: Firstly, inheritance, while valauable, is often over-used. Secondly, WCF *does* support inheritance. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter whether or not you think about SOA as implemented by SOAP, REST or messaging, services are document-centric. [Services are not object-oriented](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/31/AtTheBoundariesApplicationsAreNotObjectOriented.aspx).

While polymorphism is a strong design tool in OOD, it's not applicable in SOA because SOA modeling doesn't involve classes.

Comment: Thank you. I read in your blog that "translation layers that can translate the DTOs to properly encapsulated domain objects" is not the best idea. What are the proven alternatives? Could you please provide links to some good code demonstrations (if possible in WCF)?

Answer (score 4):

> I find Inheritance and concept of base class as the strongest point of OOP.

Don't overestimate power of inheritance - almost all GoF patterns are about avoiding wrong usage of inheritance.

> But this is not encouraged in SOA.

No it is generally not encouraged. Why? Because in SOA you have a service providing some operations. The service itself is defined by service description (contract / interface). In case of SOAP services contract is described in WSDL. If you need to have another service providing same set of operations with little bit different behavior you you will just implement interface again and target client to a new service (by providing new endpoint URL). So inheritance with service contract "works" but it doesn't work in the same way with data contracts.

Each service operation usually accepts some data and return some data. These data are again described in service description. In case of SOAP services data are described as XSD. When you send data from client to service (or in reverse direction) data must be serialized and destination must be able to deserialize them (unless you want to work with SOAP envelopes directly or unless you want to use xsd:any = untyped XML as passed data). If you want to use inheritance in data contract you must somehow include information about derived contracts into the service description. Only after including this information into service description you can inform service consumers about existence of inherited data contracts (they need this information to work with derived types).

WCF offers ability to work with inherited data contracts. You can use [`KnownTypeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx), [`ServiceKnownTypeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx) attribute or [`DataContractResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358759.aspx). You can also check this [great article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598929.aspx) for more details.

In case of non interoperable and tightly coupled systems (non SOA) you can also use [`NetDataContractSerializer`](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/08/wcf-using-the-netdatacontractserializer-to-share-your-type/) which allows you to use inheritance without any limitations because each serialized message contains information about CLR type needed for deserialzation and clients with service should share data contract assemblies.

Comment: You do not need NetDataContractSerializer to have an inheritance structure in your class hierarchy.  DataContractSerializer works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

One reason why inheritance is not recommend in SOA is because your code is Model centric. You have well defined entry and exit models, and your code should translate between the two, plus perform any business logic.

Having inheritance would just mean that the relationships between your objects are hard to model and/or change over time. Basically this means using POCO model objects.

If you want to add business logic to your you cound use mixins to mimic inheritance.